# flag.FlagSet.String returning `flag needs an argument:`

Tags: go, go-flag

`cmd` is an instance of instance of a `*Command` struct in the form of:

```
type Command struct {
  Run func(cmd *Command, args []string)
  Flag flag.FlagSet

  Usage string
  Short string
  Long string
}
```

The problem that I am running into is that:

```
if err := cmd.Flag.Parse(args[1:]); err != nil {
  os.Exit(2)
}
```

Is returning the an `err` which reads: `flag needs an argument: -list` when I run my program. Here's how I have my flag setup:

```
func init() {
  cmdAddSensor.Flag.String("list", "default", "List all of the supported sensors")
}
```

Which follows the documentation [here](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#FlagSet.String). I'm confused because the [flag command line syntax](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/) mentions that any of these forms will work:

```
-flag
-flag=x
-flag x  // non-boolean flags only
```

When I run my executable with another argument (i.e.: `./myexecutable blah -list garbage` my flag works as expected. I'm trying to understand why line `892` of the [flag package's source](https://golang.org/src/flag/flag.go) is getting triggered by my setup.

I'm a Go newbie, so it's possible I'm missing something pretty obvious here. Thanks in advance!

Comment: From that last part, is says to me that the 0 index in `args` is actually the first argument, rather than the name of the executable (as is the case usually).  Are you _sure_ the first index is the executable name?  Print out your args before trying to parse them to double check.

Comment: @Kaedys I think I may have misspoken—the 0 index in `args` isn't `myexecutable`. It's `blah` (in my example above). index 1 is `-list` and index 2 is `garbage`

Comment: Ah.  Well, `-list` is a string.  The `-flag` format is only really valid for booleans (where it sets the boolean to `true`).  The string form would be `-flag value`, or `-flag ""` if you want to make it explicitly empty.

Comment: Kinda has to be that way, incidentally.  Otherwise, what is the result of `-list -foo -bar`?  Is the second argument the value of `-list`, or is it the `-foo` flag itself, and `-list` is supposed to be empty?  That type of ambiguity is why `-boolflag false` isn't allowed.

Comment: @Kaedys aha! You're absolutely right, and thanks for your follow up explanation. It helped clear it up in my head. using `Flag.Bool` made it so that I could use a flag without an argument. New line: `cmdAddSensor.Flag.Bool("list", true, "List all of the supported sensors")`